# Regex XSLT, extract match

Tags: regex, xslt

I am using XSLT 2.0 and trying to extract the caracterer regex needed.

I tried it out with tokenize(), but is more puzzling.

```
  <xsl:value-of select="tokenize('2.0-Cloverleaf-3d', '-')" />
```

By the result is: **2.0**, the result should be returned is: **3**. The string is (2.0-Cloverleaf-**3**d).

I preferred to do it in this way:

```
  <xsl:if test="matches(x:td/x:p, '.+3d$')">
    true
  </xsl:if>
```

Is there any function to get the character you need, without requiring an "if"?. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I think I'll leave it like that.

```
<xsl:variable name="places">
  <xsl:if test="matches(x:td/x:p, '.+3d$')">3</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="matches(x:td/x:p, '.+4d$')">4</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="matches(x:td/x:p, '.+5d$')">5</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

But if there is a better way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: What character you want to return or get? I think you just want to check if string ends with '3d' for this we have one more function in 2.0 which is ends-with(), but it returns boolean. And if you have fixed length you may also use substring().

Comment: I like that, ends-with(). thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use replace, to replace everything with the part you need.

In XPath 2:

```
replace(x:td/x:p, '^.*([0-9])d$', '$1')
```

In XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(x:td/x:p, '^.*([0-9])d$', '$1')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `tokenize()` but collect the tokens into a variable first.

```
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(x:td/x:p,'-')"/>
```

Then select the last token and use `substring()` to get the digit.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(item-at($tokens, 3), 1, 1)" />
```